# How to organize elements in a XSL file to convert a XML into HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am pretty new to xml and I am struggling with the conversion into html with xsl. I've been looking for xsl tutorials in vain... I don't grasp the logic of the architecture.
I am trying something really basic :
For example, I don't understand where and when to put the "apply-templates" elements. 
Aso, I can't see how to organize the html elements you've created among those you've converted from xml. Am I making any sense ? 
Here is a piece of "code" to incorporate  under  and over the `<section>`s :

```
    <xsl:template match = "curriculum">
    <html>
    <body>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="$title"/></h1>
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Any insight would be most welcome !
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're asking for a XML tutorial and SO is not the place to do that. There are tons of such things on the 'net so I'm surprised you can't find one.

Comment: I found some. I am just not able to understand them and believe me I have been trying. I am sorry that this is SO not the place to ask for some help... I honestly didn't mean to waste your time...

Comment: I didn't say you can't ask for help. You are asking how to make XML/XSL work which is too broad. You need to ask a specific question about a specific problem as outlined in the Help section.

Comment: Then you were right, I shouldn't have asked because I can't reformulate those two questions more precisely because I just don't understand more than that. But I am grateful you tried, I am sure I will find something, I am sure I am not the only one completely out of my depth !!